# How do i do calculations on things that are in a tuple expression?

Tags: recursion, elixir

Hey I'm new to Elixir (just started three days ago) and I'm trying to write a program that can calculate derivatives and I'm stuck at trying to simplify the expression for ease of reading. Only done Java and C earlier.
So I have defined this at the top

```elixir
defmodule Deriv do
  @type literal() :: {:num, number()} | {:var, atom()}
  @type expr() ::
          literal() | {:add, expr(), expr()} | {:mul, expr(), expr()}
          | {:exp, expr(), literal()} | {:div, literal(), expr()} |
          # {:ln, literal(), expr()} | {:ln, literal(), literal()}
          {:ln, expr()}
```

And I'm trying to simplify the expression I get from running this test

```elixir
def test_exp2() do
    e = {:exp, {:add, {:mul, {:num, 2}, {:var, :x}}, {:num, 3}}, {:num, 2}}
    d = deriv(e, :x)
    IO.write("Expression: #{p_print(e)}\n")
    IO.write("Derivative of expression: #{p_print(d)}\n")
    IO.write("Simplified: #{p_print(simplify(d))}\n")
    :ok
  end
```

So I have these function already that simplifies the expression when we do multiplications with 0 and 1, shown below

```elixir
def simplify({:mul, e1, e2}) do
    simplify_mul(simplify(e1), simplify(e2))
  end
  def simplify_mul({:num, 0}, _) do {:num, 0} end
  def simplify_mul(_, {:num, 0}) do {:num, 0} end
  def simplify_mul({:num, 1}, e2) do e2 end
  def simplify_mul(e1, {:num, 1}) do e1 end
  def simplify_mul({:num, n1}, {:num, n2}) do {:num, n1 * n2} end
```

But I can't get a function that does the multiplication thing mention above to work. The problem is that I don't know the syntax to use.

The output from running this is `2*(2*x + 3)*2` but I would like it to be `(8*x + 12)`
So I want some kind of function like `simplify_mul({:num, n1}, e2)` where I multiply the number n1 with everything in the expression e2. I've tried things like

```elixir
def simplify_mul({:num, n1}, {:mul, {:num, mulnum1}, e2}) do
    {:mul, {:num, n1*mulnum1}, e2}
  end
```

but it didn't work. Anyone know how one would go about doing this?

Edit:The code minus some test functions

```elixir
defmodule Deriv do
  @type literal() :: {:num, number()} | {:var, atom()}
  @type expr() ::
          literal() | {:add, expr(), expr()} | {:mul, expr(), expr()}
          | {:exp, expr(), literal()} | {:div, literal(), expr()} |
          # {:ln, literal(), expr()} | {:ln, literal(), literal()}
          {:ln, expr()}
def test_exp2() do
    e = {:exp, {:add, {:mul, {:num, 2}, {:var, :x}}, {:num, 3}}, {:num, 2}}
    d = deriv(e, :x)
    IO.write("Expression: #{p_print(e)}\n")
    IO.write("Derivative of expression: #{p_print(d)}\n")
    IO.write("Simplified: #{p_print(simplify(d))}\n")
    :ok
  end
def test_ln() do
    e =
      {:mul, {:num, 2}, {:ln, {:exp, {:add, {:mul, {:num, 2}, {:var, :x}}, {:num, 3}}, {:num, 2}}}}
    d = deriv(e, :x)
    IO.write("Expression: #{p_print(e)}\n")
    IO.write("Derivative of expression: #{p_print(d)}\n")
    IO.write("Simplified: #{p_print(simplify(d))}\n")
    :ok
  end
###### Our derivatives rules #######

  # derivative of a constant
  def deriv({:num, _}, _) do {:num, 0} end

  # derivative of x to the power of one
  def deriv({:var, v}, v) do {:num, 1} end

  # derivative of another variable than x
  def deriv({:var, _}, _) do {:num, 0} end

  # d/dx(f+g) = f'(x) + g'(x)
  def deriv({:add, e1, e2}, v) do {:add, deriv(e1, v), deriv(e2, v)} end

  # d/dx(f*g) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)
  def deriv({:mul, e1, e2}, v) do
    {:add, {:mul, deriv(e1, v), e2}, {:mul, e1, deriv(e2, v)}}
  end

  # d/dx(u(x)^n) = n(u(x))^(n-1)*u'(x), where n is a real number
  def deriv({:exp, u, {:num, n}}, v) do
    {:mul, {:mul, {:num, n}, {:exp, u, {:num, n - 1}}}, deriv(u, v)}
  end

  #d/dx(k/(u(x)^n)) = -nk*u'(x)/(u(x)^(n+1))
  def deriv({:div, {:num, k}, {:exp, e, {:num, n}}}, v) do
    {:div,
      {:mul,
        {:mul, {:num, k}, {:num, -n}},
        deriv(e, v)
      },
      {:exp, e, {:num, n + 1}}
    }
  end

  def deriv({:ln, e}, v) do {:div, deriv(e, v), e} end

  # d/dx(k*ln(u(x)^n)) = kn*u'(x)/u(x)
  def deriv({:mul, {:num, k}, {:exp, e, {:num, n}}}, v) do
    {:div,
      {:mul,
        {:mul, {:num, k}, {:num, n}},
        deriv(e, v)
      },
      {:exp, e, {:num, n}}
    }
  end

  ###### --------------------- #######

  #simplifies the expression by removing zeros and ones etc.
  def simplify({:add, e1, e2}) do
    simplify_add(simplify(e1), simplify(e2))
  end

  def simplify({:mul, e1, e2}) do
    simplify_mul(simplify(e1), simplify(e2))
  end

  def simplify({:exp, e1, e2}) do
    simplify_exp(simplify(e1), simplify(e2))
  end

  def simplify({:div, e1, e2}) do
    simplify_div(simplify(e1), simplify(e2))
  end

  def simplify({:ln, e}) do simplify_ln(simplify(e)) end

  def simplify(e) do e end

  def simplify_add({:num, 0}, e2) do e2 end

  def simplify_add(e1, {:num, 0}) do e1 end

  def simplify_add({:num, n1}, {:num, n2}) do {:num, n1 + n2} end

  def simplify_add(e1, e2) do {:add, e1, e2} end

  def simplify_mul({:num, 0}, _) do {:num, 0} end
  def simplify_mul(_, {:num, 0}) do {:num, 0} end
  def simplify_mul({:num, 1}, e2) do e2 end
  def simplify_mul(e1, {:num, 1}) do e1 end
  def simplify_mul({:num, n1}, {:num, n2}) do {:num, n1 * n2} end

  def simplify_mul({:num, n1}, {:mul, {:num, mulnum1}, e2}) do
    simplify({:mul, {:num, n1*mulnum1}, e2})
  end
def simplify_mul(e1, e2) do {:mul, e1, e2} end

  def simplify_exp(_, {:num, 0}) do {:num, 1} end

  def simplify_exp(e1, {:num, 1}) do e1 end

  def simplify_exp({:num, n1}, {:num, n2}) do {:num, :math.pow(n1, n2)} end

  def simplify_exp(e1, e2) do {:exp, e1, e2} end

  def simplify_div({:num, 0}, _) do {:num, 0} end

  def simplify_div(e1, e2) do {:div, e1, e2} end

  def simplify_ln({:num, 1}) do {:num, 0} end

  def simplify_ln({:num, 0}) do {:num, 0} end

  def simplify_ln(e) do {:ln, e} end

  # p_print functions converts from our syntax tree into strings for ease of reading
  def p_print({:num, n}) do "#{n}" end

  def p_print({:var, v}) do "#{v}" end

  def p_print({:add, e1, e2}) do "(#{p_print(e1)} + #{p_print(e2)})" end

  def p_print({:mul, e1, e2}) do "#{p_print(e1)}*#{p_print(e2)}" end

  def p_print({:exp, e1, e2}) do "(#{p_print(e1)})^(#{p_print(e2)})" end

  def p_print({:div, e1, e2}) do "(#{p_print(e1)}/#{p_print(e2)})" end

  def p_print({:ln , e1}) do "ln(#{p_print(e1)})" end
end
```

Comment: Just a tip for debugging: you might be interested in [`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2), e.g. `IO.inspect(e, label: "expression")` or [`dbg/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#dbg/2).

Comment: I fixed the formatting, was missing `lang-` in `<!-- language-all: lang-elixir -->`.

Comment: You didn't share the implementation of `deriv`, so we can't try out your example. On the other hand, this problem is only about `simplify` I think so you could "simplify" the problem and just share the expected inputs and outputs for `simplify`?

Comment: If you could clarify what you're trying to do in terms of inputs and expected outputs, that would be helpful.  Even if you could show the implementation of this in Java or C, it would be much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this is broadly on the right track, you're just short a couple of rules.

```elixir
def test do
  # the input expression is 2*(2x+3)*2
  e = {:add, {:mul, {:num, 2}, {:var, "x"}}, {:num, 3}}
  e = {:mul, {:num, 2}, e}
  e = {:mul, e, {:num, 2}}
  e |> simplify() |> IO.inspect()
end
```

Since this is only binary expressions, I've represented this as `(2 * (2x+3)) * 2`.

The first thing that can help cut down the number of cases is to swap the operands if the second one is a number but the first isn't.  You can then repeat the simplification step on the swapped result.  You're guaranteed the first operand isn't a number (you have a separate simplification step for "both numbers") so this is guaranteed to terminate.

```elixir
def simplify_mul(e1, {:num, _}=e2) do
  simplify_mul(e2, e1)
end
```

This changes the expression to `2 * (2 * (2x+3))`.  Now you can specifically match the case where you're multiplying a constant by a multiplication, and the first operand of the inner multiplication is also a constant.  This involves a deeper Elixir pattern match, but that's fine; you're not constrained to only matching the top-level structure.

```elixir
def simplify_mul({:num, n1}, {:mul, {:num, n2}, e3}) do
  {:mul, {:num, n1 * n2}, e3}
end
```

This reduces the expression to `4 * (2x+3)`.  The last step is to distribute multiplication over addition; if you're multiplying anything by an addition as the second argument, turn that into an addition of multiplications.  This will result in new multiplications that need to be recursively simplified; so long as you don't reverse this process, the easiest approach is to just simplify the resulting addition.

```elixir
def simplify_mul(e1, {:add, e2, e3}) do
  {:add, {:mul, e1, e2}, {:mul, e1, e3}} |> simplify()
end
```

```shellsession
$ elixir tmp.exs
{:add, {:mul, {:num, 8}, {:var, "x"}}, {:num, 12}}
```

You can add as many rules as you need to this rewriting; the only important thing to make sure of is that the rules do terminate.  So for example I've written a rule that "numbers must be first", but you need to take care also pairing this with a rule that "addition must be first" since multiplying a number and an addition would result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following should solve it, it added two extra accumulators:

- `p` (for the product of number literals), starting at 1
- and `m` for building a multiplication of expressions, starting at `nil` meaning there is no expression

It also moved from passing two factors to a list of factors: the benefit is that when you encountered a nested multiplication, you can just add its two factors to the list and keep processing, until the list is empty.

```elixir
  def simplify({:mul, e1, e2}) do
    simplify_mul([simplify(e1), simplify(e2)], 1, nil)
  end
  
  def simplify_mul([], p, nil), do: {:num, p}
  def simplify_mul([], p, m), do: {:mul, {:num, p}, m}
  def simplify_mul([{:num, 0} | _], _, _), do: {:num, 0}

  def simplify_mul([{:num, n1} | rest], p, m) do
    simplify_mul(rest, p * n1, m)
  end

  # nested multiplication: add factors to the list
  def simplify_mul([{:mul, e1, e2} | rest], p, m) do
    simplify_mul([e1, e2 | rest], p, m)
  end
  
  def simplify_mul([other | rest], p, nil) do
    simplify_mul(rest, p, other)
  end
  
  def simplify_mul([other | rest], p, m) do
    simplify_mul(rest, p, {:mul, m, other})
  end
```

```elixir
iex> simplify({:mul, {:mul, {:num, 2}, {:var, :x}}, {:mul, {:var, :y}, {:num, 3}}})
{:mul, {:num, 6}, {:mul, {:var, :x}, {:var, :y}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't quite solve it and unfortunately my Elixir knowledge is a bit to low to quite grasp what you have done. Implementing your code into mine and then running your example there I get `"1*2*x*y*3"` but what I want to get is preferably `6*x*y` or even `2*x*y*3`. Running my test_ln function now gives an output with lots of zeros still there as well as you can see `Simplified: 1*2*(2*((2*x + 3))^(1)*((0*x + 2*1) + 0)/((2*x + 3))^(2))`
Not really sure why all the zeros are there now.

Comment: Could you provide the input for `simplify` (as an Elixir term) that didn't provide the expected output? This would really help investigate.

Comment: I updated my answer, `simplify_mul([e1, e2], 1, nil)` obviously needed to call `simplify` on its children first: `simplify_mul([simplify(e1), simplify(e2)], 1, nil)`.

Comment: But David Maze's solution enforcing that `{:num, _}` always comes first is much more elegant and I think should be marked as the correct answer.